# Whats' the different brew and gem install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, cocoapods, homebrew

Recently while running `pod repo update`, it ask me

```
CocoaPods 1.15.0 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods`
```

So I run `sudo gem install cocoapods`. It shows all good

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.15.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.15.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

To my surprise, when running `pod --version`, it sill shows 1.12.1

After thinking a while, then I realize I have to run `brew upgrade cocoapods`.

My question is, when would I know I should run `brew` vs `gem install`?
Are they stored differently? (Do I have 2 cocoapod now?)
What are their differences?

Answer (score 1):

Gem is a package manager for the Ruby programming language and `gem install` is a command to install application. In the other hand, Homebrew is a package manager for macOS and `brew install` is also a command of installation. Both use to install packages or softwares.

If any applications were built by Ruby, you can use both to install it for MacOS. Otherwise, you only use `brew install` to install.

Comment: Thanks Dat! Can I use brew install, and later use gem to upgrade it? 
Or they are handled separately? (we need to know which we use to install, and need to use the same one to upgrade)

Comment: Yeah you can use brew install and later use gem to upgrade it.

Comment: I was doing that, and seems the gem update is not updating it. I need to use `brew upgrade` to get it working.